# How to sort using RxAndroid

Tags: android, sorting, rx-java, rx-android

How to sort my list through Rx function, My list contain three type of different source then I want to display my list sorted using date, how to apply that using RxAndroid?

```
 subscriptions.add(complaintsAPI.getComplaintsAPI(userDetails.getUsername())
            .compose(ReactiveUtils.applySchedulers())
            .map(list -> {
                List<ComplaintsRowModel> rowModel = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Complaint complaint : list.getComplaints()) {
                    rowModel.add(new ComplaintsRowModel(complaint.getDisputeNo(),
                            complaint.getOpenDate(), complaint.getArea(), complaint.getStatus()));

                    model.complaintsList.put(complaint.getDisputeNo(), complaint);
                }


                for (OnlineRequest onlineRequest : list.getOnlineRequests()) {
                    rowModel.add(new ComplaintsRowModel(onlineRequest.getRequestNo(), onlineRequest.getOpenDate(),
                            onlineRequest.getArea(), onlineRequest.getStatus()));

                    model.complaintsList.put(onlineRequest.getRequestNo(), onlineRequest);
                }

                for (LlTickets llTickets : list.getLlTickets()) {
                    rowModel.add(new ComplaintsRowModel(llTickets.getTicketNo(), llTickets.getOpenDate(),
                            llTickets.getType(), llTickets.getStatus()));

                    model.complaintsList.put(llTickets.getTicketNo(), llTickets);
                }


                return rowModel;}
            ).toSortedList(){
        //how to sort here
    }).subscribe(new RequestSubscriber<List<ComplaintsRowModel>>(view.getContext(), view.progressView) {

            @Override
                public void onFailure(RequestException requestException) {
                    view.showError(requestException);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNoData() {
                    super.onNoData();
                    isAllDataLoaded = true;
                    view.noDataFound();
                    model.setNoDataFound(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<ComplaintsRowModel> complaintsRowModels) {
                    isAllDataLoaded = true;
                    model.setRowModel(complaintsRowModels);
                    view.buildList(complaintsRowModels);
                }
            }));
```

I think in `toSortedList()` can I sort my list but I don't know the way to apply that.

Comment: Please show your models - `LlTickets`, `OnlineRequest`, `Complaint`, `ComplaintsRowModel` and explain in details (preferable with example) how you want to sort it. Otherwise your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: No need for model details just I wanna know how sorting process be apply using Rx, kind of snippet  , thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toSortedList` operator would only work on `Observable<ComplaintRowModel>` while what you have is `Observable<List<ComplaintRowModel>>`. So first you have to transform your observable with

```
flatMapIterable(complaintRowModels -> complaintRowModels)
```

to map it to an observable of the list elements. Then you can apply the sorting something like

```
toSortedList((complaintRowModel, complaintRowModel2) -> {
    Date date = complaintRowModel.getDate();
    Date date2 = complaintRowModel2.getDate();

    // comparing dates is very much dependent on your implementation
    if (date <before> date2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (date <equal> date2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
})
```

Then you get an observable of sorted list.

Comment: of course not, it highly depends on what format the date is saved

Comment: In your code it's `Date date`, that's why it's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

As per you don't want to provide specific information about your problem, there is generic answer.

1. When data object which need to be sorted implements `Comparable` or it's primitive type.

   ```
   Observable.just(3, 2, 1)
           .toSortedList()
           .subscribe(list -> System.out.print(Arrays.toString(list.toArray())));
   ```

> [1, 2, 3]

2. When data object which need to be sorted doesn't implement `Comparable` or implements it, but you need to specify how you'd like to sort data.

That sample illustrate how to sort list of objects by `val` field in descended order.

```
static class ToSort {
    Integer val;

    public ToSort(Integer val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ToSort{" +
                "val=" + val +
                '}';
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable.just(new ToSort(1), new ToSort(2), new ToSort(3))
            .toSortedList((o1, o2) -> (-1) * o1.val.compareTo(o2.val))
            .subscribe(list -> System.out.print(Arrays.toString(list.toArray())));
}
```

> [ToSort{val=3}, ToSort{val=2}, ToSort{val=1}]

Answer (score 0):

Different approach to replce the

```
// comparing dates is very much dependent on your implementation
if (date <before> date2) {
    return -1;
} else if (date <equal> date2) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Using a `static import java.util.Comparator.comparing;`
you can do comparing using method references found inside of your date object.

Ex.
In this instance `unsortedDevices` is a standard ObservableList to be used in a TablView.

```
SortedList<HistoryDisplayItem> sortedItems = new SortedList<>(unsortedDevices,
            comparingInt(HistoryDisplayItem::getNumber));
```